# Borel $\sigma$-algebras and topologies

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $id:(M,\rho_1)\to(M,\rho_2)$ is continuous, then $\cal{B}_2$$(M)\subseteq \cal{B}_1$$(M)$

where $\cal{B}_1, \cal{B}_2 $ are the Borel $\sigma$-algebras induced by the metrics $\rho_1 ,\rho_2 $ respectively.

I've understood that by continuity of f, since the pre-image of an open set is open, then open sets $U$ that are open w.r.t $\rho_2$ are also open w.r.t $\rho_1$. 
This means that if $\tau_1,\tau_2$ are topologies w.r.t $\rho_1, \rho_2$ then $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1$

But how am I able to obtain/prove that  $\cal{B}_2$$(M)\subseteq \cal{B}_1$$(M)$  must follow?

Comment: If $U$ is open w.r.t. $\rho_2$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open w.r.t. $\rho_1$. How does this imply $U$ is open w.r.t. $\rho_1$?

Comment: Regardless, if you know $\tau_2 \subset \tau_1$, then trivially $\mathcal{B}_2(M) \subset \mathcal{B}_1(M)$ since $\mathcal{B}_i(M)=\sigma(\tau_i)$ where $\sigma(X)$ is the sigma algebra generated by $X$.

Comment: I forgot to add that f is the identity function in this case

Comment: Is there someway to prove that if $\tau_2 \subseteq \tau_1 \Rightarrow \sigma(\tau_2) \subseteq \sigma(\tau_1)$?

I'm not at the stage where I can visualize it

Comment: Clearly $\tau_2 \subseteq \sigma(\tau_1)$.  Hence $\sigma(\tau_1)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains $\tau_2$.  By definition, $\sigma(\tau_2)$ is the *smallest* $\sigma$-algebra containing $\tau_2$, so necessarily it is smaller than $\sigma(\tau_1)$, i.e. we have $\sigma(\tau_2) \subseteq \sigma(\tau_1)$.

Comment: That answers it perfectly! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

> **Theorem**: If $X \subset Y$, then $\sigma(X) \subset \sigma(Y)$.

*Proof*: Since $$
\sigma(X)\equiv\bigcap_{\substack{\mathcal{M}\text{ is a }\sigma\text{-algebra}\\
X\subset\mathcal{M}
}
}\mathcal{M}
\text{ and }
\sigma(Y)\equiv\bigcap_{\substack{\mathcal{M}\text{ is a }\sigma\text{-algebra}\\
Y\subset\mathcal{M}
}
}\mathcal{M},
$$
the desired result follows.